# Username cannot contain repeating underscore or period

Tags: regex

I have always struggled with these darn things. I recall a lecturer telling us all once that if you have a problem which requires you use regular expressions to solve it, you in fact now have 2 problems.

Well, I certainly agree with this. Regex is something we don't use very often but when we do its like reading some alien language (well for me anyway)... I think I will resolve to getting the book and reading further.

The challenge I have is this, I need to validate a username based on the following criteria:

1. can contain letters, upper and lower
2. can contain numbers
3. can contain periods (`.`) and underscores (`_`)
4. periods and underscores cannot be consecutive i.e. `__` `..` are not allowed but `._._` would be valid.
5. a maximum of 20 characters in total

So far I have the following : `^[a-zA-Z_.]{0,20}$` but of course it allows repeat underscores and periods.

Now, I am probably doing this all wrong starting out with the set of valid characters and max length. I have been trying (unsuccessfully) to create some look-around or look-behind or whatever to search for invalid repetitions of period (`.`) and underscore (`_`) not sure what the approach or methodology to break down this requirement into a regex solution is.

Can anyone assist with a recommendation / alternative approach or point me in the right direction?

Comment: You forgot the digits in your regex; also, do you only want to allow ASCII letters/digits? Which regex engine are you using (that's required info for all regex questions on StackOverflow, by the way)?

Comment: Regular Expressions are still the way to go. If you use them, all the knowledge required to parse the string is inside the regex. If you don't use them, the knowledge is all over the place, and you have a bunch of for-loops, tons of string operations and millions of edge cases you'll probably forget to implement and the resulting code is even buggier and harder to read. Don't let the lecturer discourage you, If you don't know enough about anything, it is hard, if you know enough, it's easy.

Comment: Ah yes good spotting I typed that in wrong was supposed to be ^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]  This is good enough for ensuring all valid ASCII characters however I am struggling with requirement #4 without splitting into 2 expressions. In terms of Regex engine I am validating both client-side (Javascript) and server-side ASP.NET 4.5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This one is the one you need:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|([._])(?!\1)){5,20}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/eAofoqyX1em_slvs)

You can have a demo of what it matches [here](http://regexr.com?35qn2).

---

*"Either an alphanum char (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`), or (`|`) a dot or an underscore (`[._]`), but that isn't followed by itself (`(?!\1)`), and that from 5 to 20 times (`{5,20}`)."*

1. `(?:X)` simply is a *non-capturing group*, i.e. you can't refer to it afterwards using `\1`, `$1` or `?1` syntaxes.
2. `(?!X)` is called a *negative lookahead*, i.e. literally "which is not followed by X".
3. `\1` refers to the first **capturing** group. Since the first group `(?:...){5,20}` has been set as *non-capturing* (see #1), the first capturing group is `([._])`.
4. `{X,Y}` means *from X to Y times*, you may change it as you need.

Comment: That may be the fastest solution yet.

Comment: I like all of the answers offered but hats off to sp00m for this solution which I think is the most elegant so far. Of course, once explained it all makes sense :)  Quite an enjoyable challenge this one, thank you all for your contributions!

Answer (score 6):

You can use two [negative lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
^(?!.*__)(?!.*\.\.)[0-9a-zA-Z_.]{0,20}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?!  # Assert that it's impossible to match the following regex here:
 .*  # Any number of characters
 __  # followed by two underscores in a row
)    # End of lookahead
```

Depending on your requirements and on your regex engine, you may replace `[0-9A-Za-z_.]` with `[\w.]`.

@sp00n raised a good point: You can combine the lookahead assertions into one:

```
^(?!.*(?:__|\.\.))[0-9a-zA-Z_.]{0,20}$
```

which might be a bit more efficient, but is a little harder to read.

Comment: Why don't you use a single negative lookahead with an OR within it? Yours as is is going through the whole input 3 times.

Comment: @sp00m: Good point. I've edited my answer. I'm not sure how much that will affect performance, but it's certainly a good alternative.

Answer (score 6):

Don't try to shove this into a single regex. Your single regex works fine for all criteria except #4. To do #4, just do a regex that matches *invalid* usernames and reject the username if it matches. For example (in pseudocode):

```
if username.matches("^[a-zA-Z_.]{0,20}$") and !username.matches("__|\\.\\.") {
    /* accept username */
}
```

Comment: (Wasn't totally sure what you meant by "cannot be consecutive" since you said `..` was OK. But this example is meant to be illustrative anyway).

Comment: `..` is not OK. There was a problem with (missing) formatting in the original post.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: It's a javascript-esque pseudocode. I'll clarify. (The original question didn't specify a language)

Comment: @sp00m: Sometimes, one regex just gets too complicated. And, besides, my solution works even if your regex engine doesn't support advanced stuff like lookahead/lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

For your answer above
I've tried to do what it you says on the account but it still says
The account name shall be a combination of letter, number or underscore
then after i am try do that  then app reject that account
So  write me a sample of the correct registration data according to the name I want to register is PACIFIC CONCORD INTERNATIONAL
And put signs and underscores on this name correctly so that the site accepts it
Thank you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33845029)